# MySQL - SubQuery within a Select

Tags: mysql, subquery, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

I'm not sure if this is possible, and it's certainly tough to describe.

I'd like to return a `SELECT` query in this manner:

```
pID | Name | Email            | Dog Name   | Fish Name
-------------------------------------------------------
44  | John | john@email.com   | Scruffy   | 
56  | Jane | jane@email.com   |           | Puffer
72  | Joe  | joe@email.com    |  Sparky   | Gill
```

There are 3 tables:
`tbl_option_fields`
`tbl_person`
`tbl_person_optionals`

The first table simply defines unlimited optional fields.  Here are the columns:

```
optid | opttitle
------------------
1     | Dog Name
2     | Fish Name
3     | Email
```

The second table is simply where I keep data for people:

```
pID |  Name
---------------
44   | John 
56   | Jane 
72   | Joe
```

The last table let's me store any optional data that exists for a `pID`

```
ID |  pID  | optid  | optval
----------------------------------
1   | 44   |   1    | Scruffy
2   | 56   |   2    | Puffer
3   | 72   |   1    | Sparky
4   | 72   |   2    | Gill 
5   | 72   |   3    | joe@email.com
6   | 56   |   3    | jane@email.com
7   | 44   |   3    | john@email.com
```

The result of the SELECT statement needs to show the `opttitle` in the header of the result.
I'm not good at sub-queries, and this one may be a doozy.

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT p.*, opt.optval
FROM `tbl_person` p
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_person_optionals` opt ON p.pID = opt.pID 
WHERE 1
```

This query causes duplicating results, and I believe I understand why.

```
pID | Name | optval            
-----------------------------
44  | John | john@email.com   
44  | John | Scruffy   

56  | Jane | jane@email.com
56  | Jane | Puffer

72  | Joe  | joe@email.com  
72  | Joe  | Sparky  
72  | Joe  | Gill
```

Hopefully I'm explaining that I want to display the Optional Fields horizontally, rather than a new record in the rows.
Can this be done?

Comment: What you're looking for is a pivot query, but mysql doesn't support them directly. There's workarounds, but they make for ugly syntax, and they don't scale up automatically as you add/want more columns in the pivotted result.

Comment: And that's probably what I needed to hear.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want is a pivot table. This can be done in MySQL, like [this article describes in full, glorious detail](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78).

However, in order to archieve what you want with your current table design you would have to add a `SELECT`-operator for *every* option you have in your table `tbl_option_fields`. With only a few options this is manageable, but the more options you have, the more messy your statement will become (and eventually slower to perform).

Another downside is your statement has to be adjusted everytime a new options comes into existence.

Basically either you have to live with it or adjust your table design. There might be a few more option, but I guess it boils down to those two.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
SELECT p.pID, p.Name, 
  MAX(IF(opt.optid=3, opt.optval, NULL)) AS `Email`,
  MAX(IF(opt.optid=1, opt.optval, NULL)) AS `Dog Name`,
  MAX(IF(opt.optid=2, opt.optval, NULL)) AS `Fish Name`
FROM `tbl_person` p
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_person_optionals` opt ON p.pID = opt.pID 
GROUP BY p.pID;
```

You must know all the optid's and their column labels *before* writing this query.  This is true of MySQL but it's also true of RDBMS brands that support native `PIVOT` commands (e.g. Microsoft SQL Server).  SQL requires that you define the columns of a query before it begins examining the data; the query can't "add" more columns as it discovers distinct data values.

So you should query your first table that defines the optional fields, and use the results to dynamically write the SQL query above.

The alternative is to fetch the optional fields row by row as you showed in your example, and then write application code to fetch all the rows and rearrange them into one row per person.

Either way:  **any dynamic pivot query requires you write more application code, either before the query or after the query.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by joining the tables together and aggregating the results:

```
select po.pid, p.name,
       MAX(case when o.optId = 'Email' then po.optval end) as Email,
       MAX(case when o.optId = 'Dog Name' then po.optval end) as DogName,
       MAX(case when o.optId = 'Fish Name' then po.optval end) as FishName
from tbl_person_optionals po join
     tbl_person p
     on p.pId = p.pId join
     tbl_optionfields o
     on p.optid = o.optid
group by po.pid, p.name;
```

This assumes that you know what you want in the columns.  `Select` statements can only return a fixed set of columns, so if you want to return a separate column for each value in `tbl_optionfields`, you would need dynamic SQL (i.e. use a prepare statement).